# guillermocalvo - AdMob Plugin Unity

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, admob, show

im using this plugin [here](https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin) and it works fine but i have one question.

I have 3 scenes in my game(start, game and end) and in each of them is a prefab object of this plugin, so the ads are reloded eveytime a scene gets opened.(it a very short game so a ad just shows about 5s)

But i want to load the ads on start and in game+end scene just to show up.(that it can reload new ads itself)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefab from the sencond and the third scene and put an extra script to the prefab with the code

```
void Start(){
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject) );
}
```